# TaskCanceledException: a task was cancelled while rendering jsreport

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, jsreport

I'm trying to render a `jsreport` that contains too much data and when it takes too long to render shows me this message:

```
TaskCanceledException: a task was cancelled.
```

If I load less data the report works well.

My question is, there is a way to avoid `TaskCanceledException` and let the rendering time take what it has to take to render the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ankit Vijay for your response, the answer has to be with the time out as you mention, my solution was the next one

I was using the jsreport embbedserver and i set the time out like this

```
embeddedReportingServer.ReportingService.HttpClientTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(40);
```

With this line of code i stop recieving this error:
**TaskCanceledException: a task was cancelled while rendering jsreport**

Then when i was testing again i got this error with the phanton process:

**Unable to render template. Error during rendering report: Timeout when executing in phantom.**

At the end i solved it by adding configuration to my embbed server like this

```
Helper.embeddedReportingServer.Configuration = new
            {

                phantom = new
                {
                    timeout = 900000,
                    numberOfWorkers = 2
                },


                tasks = new
                {
                    numberOfWorkers = 2,
                    timeout = 900000,


                }

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TaskCanceledException` most likely should be coming due to timeout.

Try increase timeout through `jsreport` configuration. You can read more about jsreport configuration [here](https://jsreport.net/learn/configuration). I have not tried it myself but it should be `tasks.timeout` property.